# Starting a method if activity is started from another activity

Tags: java, android

Hi!

I'm about to ask a really dumb question, but i assure you that i've searched the web and either there is no answer (highly unlikely) or i've come across a solution but have been unable to recognize it.

Anyway, here it is: Let's say i have 2 activities, A and B. Activity B is my applications launcher activity, so when I start my app, the activity B is first run. From there, i'm going to start activity A via an intent. Now, I'm in activity A and starting activity B again via an intent. Now, having started activity B via an intent from the activity A, i want to run the method showStuff() that's inside activity B. How?

Sorry for the weird story, i'm unfortunately unable to express myself in techincal language. Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a boolean flag "showStuff" though the intent when start B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.putExtra("showStuff", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in B in onCreate

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null) {
    boolean showStuff = intent.getBooleanExtra("showStuff", false);
    if (showStuff) {
         showStuff();
     }
}
```

also in B override onNewIntent

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if (intent != null) {
        boolean showStuff = intent.getBooleanExtra("showStuff", false);
        if (showStuff) {
             showStuff();
         }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if there was no intent that called the activity (like the first time when the app launches). Would the getIntent() method return false?

Comment: getIntent will return null and if it is not null getExtra would be false if not set by A

Comment: At first, i didn't question that this way of doing it will work, but now i tried to put it in my code, and it doesn't work. The showStuff boolean will always be false and the if block never gets run. What might be the problem ?

Comment: Do you have any launch mode for B?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't exactly know what a launch mode is :D. Could you please enlighten me?

Comment: Like singleTask, singleTop and so on. In the manifest if there is a flag like android:launchMode="something". Post your manifest code for the B activity.

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.example.tryinterface.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tryinterface.SomeScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_some_screen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: I posted the manifest code for both of the activities in my project. The MainActivity can be considered as activity A (despite the misleading name) and the SomeScreen is the launcher activity (activity B in my example).

Comment: That is strange but let me edit my code and see if the new code works

Comment: Maybe I should mention that the intent that starts activity B (the activity that holds the method) is called from a subclass of PreferenceFragment actually, not from the activity A itself. I don't know if this makes any difference or not.

Comment: The change had no effect on the ouput. Here-s my code inside PreferenceFragment that starts activity B. 
                       Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SomeScreen.class);
                       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                       intent.putExtra("addToast", true);
                       startActivity(intent);

Comment: Remove intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); and see if it works

Comment: Yes, it works (I tried it before, actually), but i need the flag to be present, because otherwise i would get a pile of activities on top of each other. Have you got any suggestions to avoid this ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29451/discussion-between-hoan-nguyen-and-geekkid)